# JavaScript - Setting value of element not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a code whose snippet I have attached below (JavaScript embedded in JSP), where *rs* is result set from an SQL query. I'm trying to assign a value to the edit button dynamically. But when I check the value of the button, its printing out to be null. I have also tried doing it using the *setAttribute()* method but the result was the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
...
while(rs.next()){
                <tr>
                    <td><%=rs.getInt(1) %></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                    <td id="edit"><button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td id="delete"><button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Delete</button></td>
                    <script>
                        var v = "edit".concat("<%=rs.getInt(1)%>");
                        document.getElementById("edit").value = v;
                    </script>
                </tr>
                } 
...
```

Comment: This is not javascript.

Comment: @NVRM javascript code is embedded in the jsp code

Comment: `document.getElementById("edit")` will return the `<td>` element with an `id="edit"` attribute and HTMLTableCellElement doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: By "assign a value" do you mean adding an attribute called "value" to the element? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by setting id property to edit button instead of td element.

```
     while(rs.next()){
                <tr>
                    <td><%=rs.getInt(1) %></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                    <td><button id="edit" type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button id="delete" type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Delete</button></td>
                    <script>
                        var v = "edit".concat("<%=rs.getInt(1)%>");
                        document.getElementById("edit").value = v;
                    </script>
                </tr>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to do it via a script tag, you can achieve this by in-lining the `value` attribute just like you're doing with other `rs` values:

```
...
while(rs.next()){
    <tr>
        <td><%=rs.getInt(1) %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)" value="edit<%=rs.getInt(1)%>">Edit</button></td>
        <td id="delete"><button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
} 
...
```

If you want to do it with script, @Kaiido's comment should help you - move the `id="edit"` inside the `<button>`, but note that you want to also change it to `id="edit<%=index%>"` and add declaration and an increment of `index` in the server code. Or use another value as a differentiator, otherwise you'll end up with many `id="edit"` buttons and the script won't work as expected.